# using UIPanGesture with SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uipangesturerecognizer

Im trying to pan an SKSpriteNode using UIPanGesture, the problem is the movement is too fas(the distance is much bigger than the movement of the finger, below is the code. Im suspecting something is wrong with my addition of the current position and translation.
Your help is very much appreciated.

```
@objc func panGestureHandler(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if recognizer.state == .began {
        print("Touchdown")
        var touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
        touchLocation = self.convertPoint(fromView: touchLocation)

        if (self.atPoint(touchLocation) is SKSpriteNode){
            selectedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation) as! SKSpriteNode
        } else {
            recognizer.state = .failed 
        }


    } else if recognizer.state == .changed {

        var translation = recognizer.translation(in: recognizer.view!)
        translation = CGPoint(x: translation.x, y: -translation.y)
        let position = selectedNode.position
        selectedNode.position = CGPoint(x: position.x + translation.x, y: position.y + translation.y)
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: recognizer.view)

    } else if recognizer.state == .ended {
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: recognizer.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren’t converting to scene in your change event like in your begin

Comment: The translation value is the total translation over the life cycle of the pan event not the delta from the last reported value. For example, if you start panning from (0, 0), move 10 pixels to the right, the translation value will be (10, 0). If you continue by moving your finger 10 more pixels to the right, the translation value will be (20, 0).

Comment: Knight0fDragon: Thank you for reply. Based on an example from https://www.raywenderlich.com/1748-sprite-kit-tutorial-drag-and-drop-sprites the conversion was not there in changed state. I will try and update you.

Comment: 0x141E: Thanks for your reply. I updated my code to set the translation to zero and the end of the changed state.It is working but the lag is too big between my finger and the sprite. I also tried fixing the initial point and adding the translation, same result huge lag.

Comment: Knight0fDragon: I added the following line after the var in the changed state
translation = self.convertPoint(fromView: translation)
the point shoots of the screen

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code:

```
 @objc func panGestureHandler(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
    touchLocation = self.convertPoint(fromView: touchLocation)
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        print("Touchdown")

        if (self.atPoint(touchLocation) is SKSpriteNode){
            selectedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation) as! SKSpriteNode
        } else {
            recognizer.state = .failed 
        }


    } else if recognizer.state == .changed {

        var translation = recognizer.translation(in: recognizer.view!)
        //translation = self.convertPoint(fromView: translation)

        translation = CGPoint(x: translation.x, y: -translation.y)


        selectedNode.position = CGPoint(x: pos.x + translation.x, y: pos.y + translation.y)
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: recognizer.view)
         pos = touchLocation

    } else if recognizer.state == .ended {
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: recognizer.view)
    }
}
```

Knight0fDragon, you were the translation needed to be connected even during the changed state. 
0x141E thank you for explaining the translation.